# What ports need to be opened to play multiplayer reliably?

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-revelations, networking

So I'm trying to configure my firewall to open the right ports needed to play multiplayer.

According to [Ubisoft's Support page](http://ubisoft.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15912/p/88%2C2366):

```
...you will need to configure your router or firewall to allow the following 
network ports for the best possible connection:

ACR Ports:
UDP: 21200, 7959, 3074

Uplay Launcher:
TCP: 80, 443, 13000, 13005, 13200

Achievements
UDP & TCP: 14001
```

But it isn't clear in what direction and which applications need the ports.

I allowed all outgoing and those incoming UDP ports for ACR but I'm still getting **BAD** upload and **STRICT** NAT classification.

I temporarily enabled DMZ on my firewall and inspecting my connections when refreshing my online status, I'm seeing these requests for multiplayer:

```
0.0.0.0:54466 -> 127.0.0.1:45301 (UDP)
localhost:21200 -> 216.98.51.139:28783 (UDP) //ubisoft servers
localhost:21200 -> 216.98.51.140:28783 (UDP)
```

And these active connections:

```
localhost:12001 -> 216.240.146.139:12001 (UDP)
localhost:3074 -> 216.240.146.139:12001 (UDP)
localhost:3074 -> 216.240.146.139:12011 (UDP)
```

(nothing is coming in or out from UPlay at this point)

I want to hold off on playing until I can get the right ports set up so I won't have to worry about it later.  AFAIK, I'm going to have to open something incoming if I want to/end up playing as host but I don't know what yet.  No chance of dedicated servers here.

What am I missing here?  Do I even need to open any incoming ports?

Comment: I initially had UPnP disabled on my router.  Enabled just for the sake of testing and still nothing.  I was forced into a couple of games online and that portion seems working.  I'm guessing we're just negotiating with the master server to find players.  But is there even a host player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like I *do* need to have UPnP **enabled**.  After having it enabled and restarting my computer, the NAT classification is now declared open.  I can even see the entries to Ubisoft in the forwarding table.

Viewing the logs, I've determined that I only really need to open these ports at a minimum for normal play:

#### ACRSP.exe

```
Outgoing:
    TCP 80 (remote)
    UDP 3074 (local)

Incoming:
    None
```

#### ACRMP.exe

```
Outgoing:
    UDP 7959 (local)
    UDP 3074 (local)
    UDP 21200 (local)

Incoming:
    UDP 7959 (local)
```

#### UbisoftGameLauncher.exe

```
Outgoing:
    TCP 80 (remote)
    TCP 443 (remote)
    TCP 13000 (remote)

Incoming:
    None
```

I haven't figured out what affects the upload stat yet.  I could probably ignore that for now as I don't have any plans to use the ingame chat.

Comment: Thank you Jeff for the comprehensive info on the ports;
i try at the moment to priorize those ports in my fritbox.
How should i enter them? I can choose source port or target port or both.
is it correct to assume that (local) in your post means that ACR has that port open on the local computer, therefore i need to add that port in the "source port" section? (The fritzbox says it sees the port directions from local > internet Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Well for any help to be gained from this you need to specify your PC specs, what modem, and what router you are using. Also are you the sole owner of the network your using? Do you use a static IP or is it auto generated? Also how many other PC's share the network and do they use static or auto generated IP addresses?

Basic troubleshooting: Reset router and firewall settings to factory then try to connect to the games you would like to use. Power off the modem for a few minutes then plug it back in. Get all the latest Firmware updates for Modem/routers.

Sorry I can't do much more for you without some more info on your end.

Comment: All that info is irrelevant to the issue here.  I'm not troubleshooting here, the game is working fine.  I'm just configuring my firewall to open only the needed ports.  I just want to know what those ports are for each component of the game, nothing more.

Comment: Sorry, maybe not completely irrelevant, but I'm not sure if any of that matters here.  It's not like I'm setting up a dedicated server here (wouldn't even be possible).  I'm just trying to configure it to where the game knows that I have a perfectly fine connection.  I can play any other games fine, it's just that I'm not familiar with how the more console oriented games use the net.  Cable 10Mbps down/1.5Mbps up, dynamic but always on, home network I'm administering.  Behind a router and have a software firewall.

Comment: 9103, 9100, 10196 (UDP outbound/inbound)
80, 3081, 3105 (TCP outbound)
22350 - 22380 (TCP inbound)    Not sure if this helps or not but you might need to re-install the launcher for a fresh start..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you will ever see this, but I believe your problem is needing to set a static IP address for your computer. I was having port forwarding issues with Fable 3 and Dark Souls, until I finally found a post with instructions on how to set a static IP for port forwarding, and that this was necessary for it to work properly. Once I did that, I was finally able to play Fable 3 with my friend, who could previously connect to my game but would be booted any time the game loaded.

Comment: I know how port forwarding works. All my desktop computers within my network all have static IPs. The question here was to address the fact that UBI didnt document well what ports are actually used. And even if you have everything set up correctly, the games didnt always work well. Chalk it up to poor network code.

Comment: Ahh, I thought I saw on one of your other posts that you were using a dynamic address instead of a static one. My mistake. And yes, Ubisoft really seems to send a lot of bugs out the door. I'm having issues with this as well, which is how I ended up here. :(

Answer (score 0):

- UDP 3074 (incoming/outgoing) is for XBox Live traffic.
- UDP 7959 (incoming/outgoing) is for QuickTime Streaming Server.
- UDB 21200 incoming is ACR specific, probably because it is not known to be used by anything special.

  The TCP ones are more popular:

Outgoing:

- TCP 80 is basic web stuff, in game browser etc.
- TCP 443 for SSL trafic such as authentication and while logged in.
- As for TCP 13000.. Well, this one might mean [bad news](http://www.adminsub.net/tcp-udp-port-finder/13000), but it normally is unmapped. As long you make sure your network is clean, nothing to worry about for an outgoing TCP connection.