# Can't connect to any multiplayer matches in AC:R

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I'm trying to play some multi-player in Assassins Creed: Revelation. Unfortunately, each time I try to search for a match, I can't connect to anything and the matchmaking end up giving up. No mater which game mode, even if I choose "Play now", it rarely seem to find a game I can connect to (half an our of searching for ten minutes of game-play is not fun...)

I should add that the game says that my NAT is restricted, but as it's a school housing connection, I can't configure it. Anyway, I never had any problems with it to connect to any other multi-player games...

Is there any way to improve my chances of playing a game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I've determined](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39264/what-ports-need-to-be-opened-to-play-multiplayer-reliably) that you'll need to have UPnP enabled to increase your chances to play a game.  Without it, you can only join sessions that are in currently "waiting for players" or some games that are in progress where the host has it enabled.  If you had it enabled, you'd be able to host your own game so people could join your sessions.

See if you can convince your school if they could enable that, I'm sure other people who wants to play games that relies on it would appreciate it too.